# Search results incorrect for [tag] -keyword

Tags: bug, tags, search

When attempting to refine a tag search by excluding a keyword, the list of results grows!

I first observed this on Stack Overflow.

Here is an MCVE from Christianity:

- [Search for **[gospel]**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=[gospel]) - 24 results
- [Search for **[gospel] -john**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgospel%5D+-john) - 62 results

It's clear that the extra 38 results are not tagged whith [gospel].
The header confirms that the query has been understood as *Results not containing john tagged with gospel*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What actually happens is this: searching for `[gospel]` returns all *questions* tagged with [gospel]. If you search for `[gospel] -john` you'll get all *posts* (questions *and* answers) tagged with [gospel] (in this case, answers inherit tags from their parent questions) and then the results containing 'john' are filtered out. Questions can have multiple answers, and this results in more hits than the filtering excludes.

Compare this with the results for

- [[gospel] -john is:q](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgospel%5D+-john+is%3Aq) (21 hits) - the `is:q` limits the results to questions
- [[gospel] score:-100](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgospel%5D+score%3A-100) (89 hits) - by adding a dummy operator (score >= -100) you'll get both answers and questions

Comment: Thanks for the rational explanation. In fact, what I wanted was [gospel] -john is:a